# .nextLine() method does not take subsequent String inputs

Tags: java

I have a program that asks the user for an input of numbers and characters. For this I am using a `Scanner` class. But when I take two subsequent string inputs, the console just moves and asks the user to input the second string. The user is unable to input the first string. I have attached my code below to be more specific.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class XYZ {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x, y, z, b, c;
        String p, q;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        b = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter a new number");
        c = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter a String");
        p = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter a new String");
        q = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        x = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter 2nd number");
        y = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter 3rd number");
        z = sc.nextInt();

        ABC a = new ABC();

        a.PQR(b, c);
        a.PQR(p, q);
        a.PQR(x, y, z);
    }
}

class ABC {

    void PQR(int a, int b) {
        int res = a + b;
        System.out.println("The sum is" + " " + res);
    }

    void PQR(String a, String b) {
        System.out.println("Thye concataneted string is" + a + " " + b);
    }

    void PQR(int a, int b, int c) {
        int res = a * b * c;
        System.out.println("The product is" + " " + res);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make a dummy call to `nextLine()` after your call to `nextInt()`. The `nextInt()` isn't taking the "\n" into account.

Alternatively, and preferably, just use `nextLine()` to accept all input and whichever ones need to be `ints`, just use:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(**string**);
```

Does this help?

Comment: I have made a dummy call to next(), but still I am unable to input the first String. Also I want to use the same scanner class object for both integer and String inputs.

Comment: @PratikPaul I mistakenly wrote `next()` instead of `nextLine()`. Sorry about that!

Comment: I use the listed alternative method extensively in receiving Integer inputs from the console.

Comment: @PratikPaul Yep. That would indeed be the better way for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Thats because the Scanner#nextInt method does not consume the last newline character of your input, and thus that newline is consumed in the next call to Scanner#nextLine.

[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)

OR

If you use the nextLine() method immediately following the nextInt() method, recall that nextInt() reads integer tokens, because of this, the last newline character for that line of integer input is still queued in the input buffer and the next nextLine() will be reading the remainder of the integer line (which is empty).
- hackerrank.com

Update :
After `c = sc.nextInt();`
you need to put one more statement i.e.

```
sc.nextLine();
```

HTH!

Comment: So what would be your suggestion to input the first String

Comment: Please find updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = scan.nextInt();
    double d = scan.nextDouble();
    scan.nextLine();
    String s = scan.nextLine();

    // Write your code here.

    System.out.println("String: " + s);
    System.out.println("Double: " + d);
    System.out.println("Int: " + i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        double d = sc.nextDouble();
        sc.nextLine();
        String s = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

To take three lines of input: int,double and String

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `nextLine()` method immediately following the `nextInt()` method, recall that the `nextInt()` reads integer tokens; because of this, the last newline character for that line of integer input is still queued in the input buffer and the next `nextLine()` will be reading the remainder of the integer line (which is empty).

That's why the console asks the user to input the second string, so you can use

```
Scanner md = new Scanner(System.in);
int n      = md.nextInt();  //before using the input stream for string
String st  = md.nextLine();
```

Comment: @zx485 i will do it from the next time thanks